# 4G USB dongle only occasionally initializes to switch into green light mode and get connected

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver, wrt54gl

I bought a 4G USB modem one month ago and it used to function well and connect to internet each time that I inserted in my laptop. No physical shock or damage has occurred to it. because it have always been in a safe place. Now it occasionally encounters with problem and orange light is blinking and then blue light for seconds, but again the orange one! And the green light won't turn on. In the status it shows only 3G, and on the status it says: **Disconnected**. it also doesn't connect at all via this message:

> Service is restricted

While if I insert that Sim card in my phone, just at the same time, same location it would connect.

Sometimes at "initializing phase" it says: "Invalid PUK card, RUM card is disabled" described in this screenshot:
[image: Invalid PUK card, RUM card is disabled]

And occasionally sometimes only if I pull the sim out and insert it in the dongle again, it would work!
I tested it with different simcards from different network providers in different location the problem is just dongle or driver oriented, the green light wouldn't appear to be turned on. I reinstalled the driver again and again but still no change! I have never enabled PIN nor PUK on the sim or any other change in the sim or dongle's setting and my Sims also have not been PIN-enabled to ask me the digits. I guess that it's just a bug and I must unlock each sim by PUK characters.

I also must say this truth that since 3 hours ago, I have connected exactly with that dongle, excellent statistics of uploading and downloading, it never encounters with any problem anymore when it initialized well once on each laptop. But if it won't change to green light and won't connect, the trouble begins; even with different sims and different laptops!

Comment: It sounds somewhat broken.

Comment: dear @harrymc. Do you really think that something is broken?! because sometimes it just works very well. but only if I restart the green light won't be on anymore!

Comment: Let's try the scientific method: You say that the sim works in other devices, so it might be OK. This leaves the dongle itself, so might experiment with this on another computer for verification.